# How to reference a new cell in a table by column name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working subroutine that inserts a value into a cell, as part of a new row of a table. I'm referencing the cell to insert the data into by the column number. However, I'd like to be able to use the column/header name from the table, not a number, so that table columns can be moved without upsetting the cell references in the macro. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my sample code.

```
Sub InsertValue(ByRef iTargetCell As Integer, ByRef CellData As String, ByRef strType As String)

  Select Case strType
    ' Define the data as Text
      Case "T"
      ' Specify the number format to be used for a particular column in the new row
        NewRow.Range.Cells(1, iTargetCell).NumberFormat = "@"
      ' Insert the data for a particular column into the new row
        NewRow.Range.Cells(1, iTargetCell).Value = CellData
    ' Define the data as a number
      Case "N"
        NewRow.Range.Cells(1, iTargetCell).NumberFormat = "0"
        NewRow.Range.Cells(1, iTargetCell).Value = CellData
  End Select
End Sub
```

The variable NewRow is already publicly defined.

```
Public NewRow As ListRow
```

It is set in another subroutine.

```
Set NewRow = Range(strTableName).ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("ColName").Index
```

will return the position of the column with header "ColName" in the table

Comment: Thankyou. In a previous subroutine, I'd already set a variable (Tbl) to hold the table ListObject, so I was able to modify my subroutine to create a new variable (iColNum) to hold the column number and then used `iColNum = Tbl.ListColumns(strTargetCell).Index`